# Getting a link to a Compiled Binary on Github

Tags: github

How do you include a link to a compiled binary on Github?

Comment: You track it? `git add whatever.bin && git commit -am "added" && git push`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I was clear. I meant how do I include a link to the compiled binary like the link to download the entire source.

Comment: Have a look at the new "release" feature from GitHub. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17440511/6309)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can link to a specific file in a GitHub repo using the URL `http://github.com/<username>/<project>/blob/<branch>/<path/to/file>`. So if you track your compiled binary, you can link to it that way.

Otherwise, you can upload the compiled binary to your project's download page, and distribute that URL.

Comment: The "downloads page" feature has been removed: https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads

Comment: Note that using the `/blob/` path will not give you a path to the binary itself, but to a github web page where the binary can be downloaded _from_ (and for stuff like PDF is rendered inline as well). If you want a direct URL to the binary, use `/raw/` instead of /blob/, i.e., `https://github.com/<username>/<project>/raw/<branch>/<path/to/file>`.

Answer (score 3):

[Since 2d July 2013](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software), you now can **define a release**.

> **Releases**, a workflow for shipping software to end users.
> Releases are first-class objects with changelogs and binary assets that present a full project history beyond Git artifacts. They're accessible from a repository's homepage:

[image: homepage]

- Releases are accompanied by release notes and links to download the software or source code.
- Following the conventions of many Git projects, releases are tied to Git tags. You can use an existing tag, or let releases create the tag when it's published.
- **You can also attach binary assets (such as compiled executables, minified scripts, documentation) to a release**. Once published, the release details and assets are available to anyone that can view the repository.

[image: release]

That is what replaces the [old binary upload service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978954/6309), which was [removed in December 2012](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads)!