# How to get GitHub Clone stats?

Tags: github, statistics

There used to be a "Clones" sub-tab in the "Stats & Graphs" tab of GitHub (for example https://github.com/TeamMentor/TeamMentor-Documentation/graphs/impact) but that is gone.

Is there another way to get these stats?

It would be great if we could get [Gauges](http://get.gaug.es/) to show up Git clone, pushes, pulls, GitHub page views, etc.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

At least regarding clone, you now (August, 12th 2014) have a dedicated graph.
(In 2019: `Insights / Traffic`)

See "[Clone Graphs](https://github.com/blog/1873-clone-graphs)"

> Our traffic graphs tab shows you a lot of information about who's visiting your repository on the web.
> **We've added a new graph to this tab, showing git clone activity**.
>
> [image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/395621/3867646/2c340b8a-2009-11e4-8823-9ddda44b51e0.png_git clones traffic graph]
>
> You can use it to find out:
>
> - **how many times your repository's source code is actually cloned in a given day**, as well as
> - **how many unique GitHub users (or anonymous IP addresses) did the cloning**.
>
> For more information on traffic graphs, [check out the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-graphs#traffic).

Note you also see the Referring sites and Unique visitors

---

Update Jan. 2021: [Dr. Jan-Philip Gehrcke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145400/dr-jan-philip-gehrcke) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056638/how-to-get-github-clone-stats/25270050?noredirect=1#comment116315932_25270050):

> For periodically collecting traffic/access data (such as clones, views), I've built a GitHub Action: [`jgehrcke/github-repo-stats`](https://github.com/jgehrcke/github-repo-stats):
> it automatically:
>
> - persists the data snapshots in a git repository,
> - aggregates them, and
> - generates a report with charts that then can span the entire data collection period!
>
> Demo report in the README.

Comment: Is it possible to find who cloned ?

Comment: @Sheen Not that I know of. You might find out who *forked* (as it is a server-side operation). Not who cloned.

Comment: Its worth noting it can take a week for this information to populate

Comment: Is it possible to change the time period, e.g. to get total number of clones over the life of the repo?

Comment: @JonathanStray Not that I know of through this GitHub GUI.

Comment: For periodically collecting traffic/access data (such as clones, views), I've built a GitHub Action: https://github.com/jgehrcke/github-repo-stats -- it automatically persists the data snapshots in a git repository, aggregates them, and generates a report with charts that then can span the entire data collection period! Demo report in the README.

Comment: @Dr.Jan-PhilipGehrcke Thank you. Very interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thank you, that is kind!

Answer (score 13):

Quick update on this:
Google now offers a direct API call which can be used inside the README file on github to gather statistics directly to Google analytics.  If you have an existing Google Analytics account, you need to upgrade it to a universal account.  This is a quick button press on your admin page.  Without upgrading the new api will not work - we spent a while figuring this one out.  More info here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/?hl=en_US

Here is our new call to the google universal stats API:

```
[![analytics](http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fproject-imas%2Fapp-password&_u=MAC~&cid=1757014354.1393964045&tid=UA-XTZ530-2)]()
```

Githalytics.com is no longer needed and explains why the site is up but no longer functioning.  We found this out the hard way as Githalytics went down the end of January and we did not notice until late Feb, so we lost about a months worth of site visits stats.

Comment: If that is true that's great. while I go to verify to see if it's true a plus is deserved here:)... EDIT: true fantastic:)

Answer (score 4):

At the moment (oct 2012) the answer is, No it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Its super easy now!

Updated path:   "REPO -> GRAPHS -> TRAFFIC"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Latest one is :

github UserName >>     Repo name >>   Insight > Traphic

```
  datanapps >> GoogleExoplayer >> Insight (select Top tab) >> Traphic (select left side option)
```

Please check image flow :

[image]

Hope It will help you.