# Fetching clones and visitors via the API

Tags: github-api

If you are the owner of a repo/org you can see the number of clones and the traffic for a project.  Is there a way to fetch this via the API as well?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056638/how-to-get-github-clone-stats

Comment: Its not a duplicate.  The post doesn't describe how to retrieve the clones and traffic via the API or if it is even possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to fetch this via the API as well?

Not possible currently.