# Git repository usage tracking

Tags: git, github, tracking

I just started using Git and it is amazing. This is not a question about various commands or general Git usage. My question is that, can I track which users are cloning or pulling my repository onto their local machines?

Just to be clear. I have a repository on GitHub https://github.com/myOrganization/myRepo
Can I track who is cloning and using the code present on this repository?

**Edit:** The repository may be public or private.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198194/how-to-see-count-of-project-downloads-on-github) which is a possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338358/github-can-i-see-the-number-of-downloads-for-a-repo).

Comment: I'm not trying to get the number of downloads. I'm trying to determine who is cloning the files. The links are helpful nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can really track on GitHub is who has forked it, who is watching it, who has starred it, and who has contributed code back to your repository.

If you hosted the repository on your own server, you would be able to configure the server's logging so that you can see when people connect to the server, and possibly what commands where running. I can't vouch for exactly the visibility for all the commands would be since I haven't attempted to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see when someone contributes to the project, forks it, or makes a pull request, but you cannot see everyone who downloads and uses/edits your code. If the repository is public, anyone can get the code anonymously.