# Track number of download of a release (binaries) on Github

Tags: github

So now you can manage and publish your binaries directly on Github, the feature is back from early this month ([source](http://gigaom.com/2013/07/09/oops-github-did-it-again-relaunches-binary-uploads-after-scuttling-them/)).

I've been looking around Github interface and I haven't seen a download tracker. This is a feature Google Code offer and I was wondering if Github has the same.

Please note, I am not interested to know the number of download of a repo, this is [a different topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338358/github-can-i-see-the-number-of-downloads-for-a-repo).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the GitHub API to get the `download_count` among other things for a single release asset:

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset

This is how it looks currently, but please check the link above just in case anything changed since this answer was written.

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:id`

`{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/assets/1",
  "id": 1,
  "name": "example.zip",
  "label": "short description",
  "state": "uploaded",
  "content_type": "application/zip",
  "size": 1024,
  "download_count": 42,
  "created_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
  "updated_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z"
}`

Answer (score 17):

Based on Petros answer, I used the two following curl command:

To get the list of all releases including their id and number of
   download:

```
 curl -i  https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.manifold-preview+json"
```

For example to list all the release for the OpenRefine project:

```
 curl -i  https://api.github.com/repos/openrefine/openrefine/releases -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.manifold-preview+json"
```

Then to get details on each release (you will need to run the first query to get the release id)

```
curl -i  https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/assets/:release_id -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.manifold-preview+json"
```

With the same example to list the details including download number for `google-refine-2.5-r2407.zip`

```
curl -i  https://api.github.com/repos/openrefine/openrefine/releases/assets/6513 -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.manifold-preview+json"
```

Comment: The first request is returning an empty json array, despite the fact that github shows that my repo has releases. Does this answer need updating?

Comment: The first command works, and I see an `id:` field but no `download_count` field.  Attempting the 2nd method (but tacking on the `id` to eh URL) results in `HTTP 404 Not Found`

Comment: It looks like now the syntax is `curl -i  https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:releaseID -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.manifold-preview+json"` - ie. remove the `assets/` path.  I still don't see a `download_count` field though, not sure why.

Comment: I just double check both queries and they work fine. I have them in a cron script that run daily. I will update the answer with concrete example

Answer (score 1):

You can add a badge to your github repo.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672242/adding-github-download-count-badge-to-readme-mark-down) for more details.

Also, there is a nifty project that shows all of this data in a nice website which is over here: https://www.somsubhra.com/github-release-stats/