# Adding GitHub Download Count Badge to Readme Mark Down

Tags: github, shields.io

I would like to add a badge that counts the total number of downloads that happen for one of my projects that I have on GitHub. I came across this page that has all the image shields

> https://shields.io/
>
> [![Github
>   Releases](https://img.shields.io/github/downloads/atom/atom/latest/total.svg?style=plastic)](https://github.com/my-githug-user/my-github-project)

Any ideas on how I could add this to my project in GitHub?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to insert it as an image into your `README`. If your `README` is markdown (README.md) that should be like:

Syntax:

```
[![Github All Releases](https://img.shields.io/github/downloads/<-- User Name-->/<-- Your Repo Name-->/total.svg)]()
```

Example

```
[![Github All Releases](https://img.shields.io/github/downloads/atom/atom/total.svg)]()
```

If you click on the badge on shields.io you can copy-paste markdown syntax you need to insert into `README.md`

Comment: How does it count the downloads of my project that I have on GitHub?

Comment: I did in fact add it to my README, but it shows a total download of 755k which is not true for my project!

Comment: oh, sorry, you have to replace `atom/atom` with your username/project_name

Comment: Hi  @DmitriyBudnik , My badge show zero downloads, even though people have downloaded it. Any idea why?

Comment: It depends on way you distribute your software. I guess it only counts downloads of packaged releases e.g. .zip files. Please refer to shields.io page: https://shields.io/category/downloads for details

Answer (score 4):

Check out [PePy](http://pepy.tech/) for receiving the download count of your repository and the code for your badge. Here's an example:

https://pepy.tech/project/video2tfrecord

Comment: the link attached is broken