# GitHub Track Download Count

Tags: git, github

We have a zip file hosted in a private internal GitHub repository controlled by the Organization, we just want to track the number of times the zip file gets downloaded from the repository. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Is the zip file an artifact?

Comment: Yes, it is an artifact inside the repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding GitHub Download Count Badge to Readme Mark Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672242/adding-github-download-count-badge-to-readme-mark-down)

Comment: Thank you for this reference! It looks really interesting but unfortunately it may not be applicable for us. Ours is a private internal repo specific for the organization, so we may not be able to use "shields.io" as it will be difficult for it to access for private Git repo.