# Github API Returns Empty Assets For Release Array

Tags: ios, github, repository, github-api

I am trying to track the download_count of a gitHub release via the gitHub api.  I don't need much, I just want to see what it is.

I'm trying to get this information: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#response

As you can see from the URL, the return includes a "download_count" key, but unfortunately, my assets array is entirely empty.

By Using This:

```
NSString * owner = @"...";
NSString * repo = @"...";
NSString * repoId = @"...";

// Get Release Info
NSString * releaseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.github.com/repos/%@/%@/releases", owner, repo];

// Get Assets List Specifically
NSString * assetsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.github.com/repos/%@/%@/releases/%@/assets", owner, repo, repoId];

NSURL * gitAssetsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:releaseURL];
NSData * gitAssetsRawData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:gitAssetsURL];
NSString * gitDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData :gitAssetsRawData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", gitDataString);
```

Everything outputs fine, but my assets array is always empty.  I do have releases, and the assets array is empty on all of my repositories.

Comment: The assets array will be empty if you didn't upload any binaries with your release when you created it. By default, the release will have a ZIP archive for the source, but that doesn't count as an asset. If you have uploaded an asset with a release, and are still getting an empty array -- mind sharing a link for that release?

Comment: Hi Ivan, here's my release: https://github.com/LoganWright/SimpleCam/releases do I have to upload it as a lib.a file for it to count as an asset?  I simply selected a release on github.com

Comment: Assets are binaries you can upload when creating a release. Try creating a release and look for the "Attach binaries by dropping them here or selecting one." text. We track download counts only for those assets, not for releases themselves (currently).

Comment: I have this question as well. I did upload an asset to my release, and I can curl the release info json, so I think my access token is fine (right?) -- but the assets array is still empty.

Comment: ill also mention that the files show up in the body section of the url, just not the assets one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered by Ivan in Comments, but just to close the question,

Ivan - "Assets are binaries you can upload when creating a release. Try creating a release and look for the "Attach binaries by dropping them here or selecting one." text. We track download counts only for those assets, not for releases themselves (currently)."

Comment: So it means you have to manually create a zip instead of using the one created automatically by GitHub ?

Comment: So [this github help page](https://web.archive.org/web/20200119081902/https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/getting-the-download-count-for-your-releases) is just massively misleading - wonder how many hours its existence has wasted :D

Answer (score 0):

@Logan's answer is correct, but I think it should be noted as well that if you're seeing an empty list but did download some files into the release, that you should make sure you used the binaries download. I read his answer and thought that I had done everything correctly.

It turns out there are two sections in the UI, and I missed the binaries one completely. There's a larger (body) section, where you can add files, and right under that, there's a smaller binaries upload section. That was what I missed when I couldn't figure out why my assets were only showing up in the json under "body."