# GitHub API get a single release doesn't work

Tags: github

I want to see the number of downloads for the repository.
I saw the below reference for it.
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release

Unlike the reference, my result show there is no data at assets part.

Command at windows DOS prompt

```
C:\Users\Andy>curl https://api.github.com/repos/phpoc/arduino-Phpoc/releases/13915554
```

The below is the result with "Get a single release".
As you can see, there is no data at assets part.

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/phpoc/arduino-Phpoc/releases/13915554",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/phpoc/arduino-Phpoc/releases/13915554/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/phpoc/arduino-Phpoc/releases/13915554/assets{?name,label}",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/phpoc/arduino-Phpoc/releases/tag/v1.5.0",
  "id": 13915554,
  "node_id": "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTEzOTE1NTU0",
  "tag_name": "v1.5.0",
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "Release v1.5.0",
  "draft": false,
  "author": {
    "login": "phpoc",
    "id": 17853377,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE3ODUzMzc3",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/17853377?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/phpoc",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/phpoc/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2018-11-09T06:43:25Z",
  "published_at": "2018-11-09T08:58:43Z",
  "assets": [

  ],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/phpoc/arduino-Phpoc/tarball/v1.5.0",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/phpoc/arduino-Phpoc/zipball/v1.5.0",
  "body": "## Precautions\r\n- When using this Arduino library, you must use the appropriate version of the flash files and firmware.\r\n  > this arduino library(v1.5.0) + flash files (v1.5.0) + firmware (v1.5.0) ***recommended***\r\n  > this arduino library(v1.5.0) + flash files (v1.0.2) + firmware (v1.3.1)\r\n\r\n## Release Notes\r\n- Revision: 1.5.0\r\n- Date: 2018. 11. 09.\r\n- SPPC(Serial Phpoc Procedure Call) support\r\n- spi protocol v2 support\r\n- new class : Sppc\r\n- new member functions\r\n  > PhpocClient : command, avaiableForWrite\r\n  > PhpocServer : beginWebSocketText, beginWebSocketBinary\r\n- Phpoc\r\n  > begin boot wait support (500ms)\r\n  > clear smtp MSA in begin()\r\n  > cache v2 support : NetCache\r\n- PhpocServer\r\n  > WebSocket path table support\r\n  > beginWebSocket : remove path argument default value (NULL)\r\n  > new beginWebSocket argument : proto\r\n  > proto setup bug fix\r\n  > add 'connected' log message\r\n- PhpocClient\r\n  > SSL \"method client\" support\r\n  > new static/public flags : client.conn_flags, client.init_flags\r\n- PhpocEmail : tcp0 busy bug fix (\"tcp0 ioctl close\" => \"tcp0 close\")\r\n- remove SSL/SSH server\r\n- new library metadata : includes=Phpoc.h\r\n- new boot log : product name, firmware/package version\r\n- examples\r\n  > add new comments & tutorial URL\r\n  > new example URL : example.phpoc.com/asciilogo.txt\r\n  > new example URL : example.phpoc.com/remote_addr\r\n  > new examples : WebSerialPlotter, WebRemotePad\r\n"
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to check the specific release version and that version is the "/releases/tag/v1.5.0".

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180185/github-api-returns-empty-assets-for-release-array Does that help? From that other question, it appears that, if a zip binary isn't uploaded, no assets will appear. Actually, I can see that there's a zip in the repo, so maybe not

Comment: I've been googling "github api releases assets array empty" and every link I visit claims that this is on the maintainer's end, that a proper "release" has not been created, so it looks like you're doing everything right on the API end.

Comment: @Houseman thank you for your answer. Now I got it. They don't support the download counter for release themselves. T.T