# Is there a way to know who downloads my Github repository

Tags: github, repository, fork

Is there a way to know who downloads my Github repository?

I need to verify at least a few people are interested in my Open Source Software project to get some governmental financial support.
So, my questions are:

- How may I be able to check the IDs (or, even better, the emails) of the downloading people.
- In relation to that, can I limit my repository downloadable only through forking in Github?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How may I be able to check the IDs (or, even better, the emails) of the downloading people.

That does not seem to be possible. You only have [statistics](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/), but not on downloads (unless you are talking about [downloads of the releases associated with your project](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-the-download-count-for-your-releases/)), or on [clones of your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339085/6309).

> In relation to that, can I limit my repository downloadable only through forking in Github?

That also is not available. Forking is mandatory if a user wants to contribute back (push back) to your repo. Otherwise, a direct clone is enough.