# Any way to see the last/number of times a repo has been accessed/downloaded on github?

Tags: git, github

Our org is running out of space on our account, and we've been trying to cull some older repos. The trouble is that some of the older repos may still be dependencies of active services (even if they have not been updated in years).

I know we can track clones, but as far as I've been able to see, we can't see direct downloads/pulls.

For example, we have some ruby services whose gemfiles point to repos. These will pull the repo, but not clone it, and we don't know how to check this.

Is there a solution to our problem?

Answer (score 1):

Downloads/pull: not really, because:

- there is [no downloads statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4338358/6309)
- there is no [pull event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/) which would have allowed you to monitor them through webhooks.