# Could I see how many times my github project was downloaded without github API?

Tags: github

My teacher asked me to count how many times our github project has been downloaded. I know Github API can provide download counts for all releases, but in my case it doesn't work because we didn't upload archive files in releases.
Is there another way to do this job? Maybe any tools in marketplace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github: Can I see the number of downloads for a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339085/5517435)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github: Can I see the number of downloads for a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338358/github-can-i-see-the-number-of-downloads-for-a-repo)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have read this one but someone said it's impossible to count downloads of non-asset files (Source code(zip) and Source code(tar.gz)). That was in 2016, can I do this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> someone said it's impossible to count downloads of non-asset files (Source code(zip) and Source code(tar.gz)). That was in 2016, can I do this now?

Not to my knowledge: those specific data are not publicly exposed.
Maybe GitHub support has access to internal data about those.

---

This is different from download_count for a *release* artifact (which is not the same as the project source code archive, zip or tgz).
See "[List releases for a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository)", which does include a `download_count` field per asset.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have contact Github Support.