# Why don't Github has simple method/software like Filezilla to upload files?

Tags: github, git-bash

It is very time consuming to write commands on Git Bash. Also it is very hard to understand for a beginner.
Why don't Github has simple method/software like Filezilla to upload files?
It should be simple like enter username password, select repository and click upload/synchronize button.
What do you say?

Comment: You are basically asking: *Why [tag:git] is so complicated?" - which is also non-constructive.

Comment: You might be interested in the new "release" feature in GitHub: see [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10652734/6309).

Answer (score 2):

As a source code repository, the goal for a DVCS (Distributed Version Control system) like Git (or Mercurial for that matter), and web front-end like GitHub, is *not* to "upload files, but to record commits (new revision of a full tree representing a coherent state of your project).

So the focus isn't at the file level, but at the project level.

If you look to a repository which offer an "upload" interface, consider an [artifact repo](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/why) like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), which [allows you to upload](http://mpashworth.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/adding-microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-driver-to-nexus-and-local-maven-repository/) any type of artifacts (files, binaries, pictures, ...)

[image: Nexus]

[image: Nexus upload]

[image: Nexus uploaded]

But that serves a very different purpose than a DVCS.

---

If your question is more about uploading binaries for a release, you now ([2d July 2013](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software)) can do so!

> **Releases**, a workflow for shipping software to end users.
>   Releases are first-class objects with changelogs and binary assets that present a full project history beyond Git artifacts. They're accessible from a repository's homepage:

[image: homepage]

> - Releases are accompanied by release notes and links to download the software or source code.
> - Following the conventions of many Git projects, releases are tied to Git tags. You can use an existing tag, or let releases create the tag when it's published.
> - **You can also attach binary assets (such as compiled executables, minified scripts, documentation) to a release**. Once published, the release details and assets are available to anyone that can view the repository.

[image: release]

That replaces the [old binary upload service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978954/6309), which was [removed in December 2012](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads).

Comment: Pictures from http://mpashworth.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/adding-microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-driver-to-nexus-and-local-maven-repository/