# How to create a builds repository automatically updating with each commit?

Tags: git, build, binaryfiles

In parallel to my source code's git repository I'd like to have a way to access the history of builds as well. Sure enough I could manually create files/directories à la `67b75589ba57b90e83f9b9a121f8c4b61d0ea897.exe` (or using a naming system relative to the most recent tag), but that's rather unpleasant. A nice thing to have instead would be a second git repository (yes, I know git is not optimal for binaries, but they are small and one could still have a shallow clone) with the same commit messages but containing only the binaries.

To make clear what I mean, say there's a source file `source.c`, which compiles into `application.exe`, and commit 67b75589ba57b90e83f9b9a121f8c4b61d0ea897 of the source repository modifies `source.c` with a commit message "Fixed issue #5123". Then the parallel repository should as automatically as possible contain a new commit with the new `application.exe` and a commit message "fixed issue #5123" (maybe additionally referring to the original commit id).

I'd probably implement this via a post-commit hook which runs the compilation (aborting with a warning on failure), extracts the most recent commit id and message and commits the binaries to a separate repository. But maybe you can suggest a better solution - it doesn't have to use git, but the potential support regression testing via `git bisect` (with pre-compiled binaries for speed-up) *would* probably outweigh git's suboptimal binary support...

Comment: That seems easier on GitHub ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17440698/6309

Comment: Indeed, that's basically what I'd like to achieve. Just offline / at my own server... I'm hoping to hear someone else has tried this before, instead of having to brew up a messy githook...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: a) hooks are not messy, they're made exactly these kinds of scenarios ("do something for every commit"), and b) Git is not intended for storing binaries, and storing build artifacts is usually considered unnecessary since you can just build them again from the given revision

Comment: @NevikRehnel a) Oh I didn't mean to suggest _hooks_ are messy, it's rather the ones that I wrote so far were messy... b) I know git is not perfect for that, but I'd like to have some way to let testers do regression tests without having to provide them with source code, and this way they could at least still `git bisect`

Answer (score 0):

I followed VonC's link and also found this: [You create on Github. We distribute for free.](http://sourceforge.net/publish/?source=github)

Comment: I don't get how this is supposed to help me. I am not talking about an Open Source project here

Comment: I apologize:  I hope the distraction wasn't too great.

Comment: No worries, it still may be helpful to someone else