# Best way to upload/deploy jar files in Github

Tags: java, git, github

I've used Google code in the past and had the ability to upload runnable jar files for download, now I am using GitHub and understand it had a download tab where developers were able to upload files (i.e. a runnable jar file), unfortunately it is deprecated now.

For non developers to download the whole project as a zip file and compile it, is a bit complicated. Is there another/better way to deploy/upload a runnable jar files on GitHub for download?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Since 2d July 2013](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software), you now have a new way to "upload runnable jar files for download" , through a **release**.

> **Releases**, a workflow for shipping software to end users.
>   Releases are first-class objects with changelogs and binary assets that present a full project history beyond Git artifacts. They're accessible from a repository's homepage:

[image: homepage]

- Releases are accompanied by release notes and links to download the software or source code.
- Following the conventions of many Git projects, releases are tied to Git tags. You can use an existing tag, or let releases create the tag when it's published.
- **You can also attach binary assets (such as compiled executables, minified scripts, documentation) to a release**. Once published, the release details and assets are available to anyone that can view the repository.

[image: release]

That now replaces the [old binary upload service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978954/6309), which was [removed in December 2012](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads).

Answer (score 2):

You would have to include them in the repo, which is not wise because Git does best with source code, not binary files.

Perhaps a better option is
[to use S3](http://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads)
as they recommend, or Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

Github used to have a download link where you could upload your binaries.

As of the end of 2012, the download option has been removed.

My personal favorite is to use source forge.

Instructions on integrating github with source forge can be found here

http://sourceforge.net/publish/?source=github

Here is an example of an arduino project that uses github for source, and source forge for binaries.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/all-spark-cube/

https://github.com/spudstud/All-Spark-Cube